# How to split a list of long strings into a new list with shorter strings?

Tags: python-3.x, list, element

I want to split the `text of a novel` into its `chapters` and those chapters again into `chucks of 1000 words` each.
I already created a list with my chapters but now I have no clue how to split those `list-elements` *automatically* into another list, to create a list for each chapter with the respective chunks.

I can do it for one element but I'm really stuck here. I don't think that the solution is complicated but I just don't get it. (I assume some kind of loop would work?)

```
text = chapters[1]
text = text.split()
n = 1000
batch = [' '.join(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(text),n)]
```

And would it be a better way to do work with dictionaries or a data frame? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Each chapter is in batch and then within that is an array of all the words separated by 1000 words. So to access the 1st thousand words, it'd be `batch[0][0]`. Chapter 3, 5000-5999 words - `batch[2][4]`.

```
batch=[]
for text in chapters:
  print(text)
  text = text.split()
  n = 1000
  batch.append([' '.join(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(text),n)])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a one-liner, the result would be a list of lists of lists.

You provide a list of chapters, which will need to be converted in a list of chunks (another list) of size n, so the code would be something like this:

```py
chapters = [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed maximus euismod turpis sit amet venenatis.",
    "Nunc a volutpat enim, vel sollicitudin est. Maecenas semper condimentum scelerisque.",
]

n = 5

rc = [[s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)] for c in chapters if (s := c.split())]
```

The result would look like this:

```json
# List of chapters
[
    # List of chunks
    [
        # List of words
        ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,'],
        ['consectetur', 'adipiscing', 'elit.', 'Sed', 'maximus'],
        ['euismod', 'turpis', 'sit', 'amet', 'venenatis.']
    ],
    [
        ['Nunc', 'a', 'volutpat', 'enim,', 'vel'],
        ['sollicitudin', 'est.', 'Maecenas', 'semper', 'condimentum'],
        ['scelerisque.']
    ],
]
```

In order to not compute `split()` multiple times, you need to declare it as a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked like a charm. But that's not quite what I'm looking for, because splitting each word is not the right way for what I plan. @PressingOnAlways answer is better suited for my case.